# Showing Arbitrary Graph Nodes and Edges for a Network in GraphViz

Tags: graph, graphviz, graph-visualization

I'd like to draw a network, as a fully connected directed graph, with arbitrary number of nodes and edges as shown in the pic. 
[image]
What would be the easy way to draw this with GraphViz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graphviz gallery has a very similar [entry](http://graphviz.org/Gallery/gradient/cluster.html), with fancy graphic: it's as easy as replacing the names `start`, etc... with your own in the generating script. Feed it to `dot` program.

```
digraph G {bgcolor="red:cyan" gradientangle=0

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        fillcolor="blue:yellow";
        gradientangle=90;
        node [fillcolor="yellow:green" style=filled gradientangle=270] a0;
        node [fillcolor="green:red"] a1;
        node [fillcolor="red:cyan"] a2;
        node [fillcolor="cyan:blue"] a3;

        a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3;
        label = "process #1";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [fillcolor="yellow:magenta" 
             style=filled gradientangle=270] b0;
        node [fillcolor="magenta:cyan"] b1;
        node [fillcolor="cyan:red"] b2;
        node [fillcolor="red:blue"] b3;

        b0 -> b1 -> b2 -> b3;
        label = "process #2";
        color=blue
        fillcolor="blue:yellow";
        style=filled;
        gradientangle=90;
    }
    start -> a0;
    start -> b0;
    a1 -> b3;
    b2 -> a3;
    a3 -> a0;
    a3 -> end;
    b3 -> end;

    start [shape=Mdiamond ,
        fillcolor="yellow:brown",
        gradientangle=90,
        style=radial];
    end [shape=Msquare,
        fillcolor="orange:blue",
        style=radial,
        gradientangle=90];
}
```

Comment: Yep, I've seen, the thing is that I am looking for something like in the picture, with dots (.), and nodes labeled from 1 to n.